# how to show all the maximum result in clingo when using the maximize?

Tags: answer-set-programming, clingo, gringo

I'm currently writing an asp program.
when I **comment the line `#maximize{S:ce(S)}.`** within the program, the answer shows as follows

```
omit the Answer 1 to 6.

Answer: 7
review(harris,english) review(ben,math) review(ben,chinese) review(nick,math) review(ben,english) review(nick,chinese) **ce(4)**

Answer: 8
review(harris,english) review(ben,math) review(ben,chinese) review(nick,math) review(nick,english) review(nick,chinese) **ce(4)**

SATISFIABLE
```

in which the answer 7 and answer 8 have the same `ce` value of `4`.

when I **uncomment the line `#maximize{S:ce(S)}.`** the answer shows as follows

```
Answer: 1
review(ben,chinese) review(nick,math) ce(2) review(harris,math) review(ben,english) review(nick,english) review(nick,chinese)
Optimization: -2

Answer: 2
review(harris,english) review(ben,math) review(ben,chinese) ce(3) review(harris,math) review(nick,english) review(nick,chinese)
Optimization: -3

Answer: 3
review(harris,english) review(ben,math) review(ben,chinese) review(nick,math) **ce(4)** review(nick,english) review(nick,chinese)
Optimization: -4

OPTIMUM FOUND
```

there is only one result of `ce(4)`, but I'd like to get all the result of the maximum value of ce, what should I do to get the two result with the value `ce(4)`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could share your command when executing clingo. I simplified your program as I am not aware of the problem you are encoding.

```
review(harris,english).
review(ben,math).
review(ben,chinese).
review(nick,math).
review(ben,english) | review(nick, english). % miss one in your problem
review(nick,chinese).
ce(4).
#maximize{S:ce(S)}.
```

Basically, the missing condition of your problem is the enumeration of  `review(ben,english)` and `review(nick, english)`.

If executing with command `clingo 0 filename.lp` the output would generate only one answer set:

```
Answer: 1
review(harris,english) review(ben,math) review(ben,chinese) review(nick,math) review(nick,chinese) ce(4) review(ben,english)
Optimization: -4
OPTIMUM FOUND
```

Similar to your attempt, if I comment the last line, two answer sets will be shown:

```
Answer: 1
review(harris,english) review(ben,math) review(ben,chinese) review(nick,math) review(nick,chinese) ce(4) review(ben,english)
Answer: 2
review(harris,english) review(ben,math) review(ben,chinese) review(nick,math) review(nick,chinese) ce(4) review(nick,english)
SATISFIABLE
```

But if you uncomment the last line and add `--opt-mode=optN` after the original command, the output would be:

```
Answer: 1
review(harris,english) review(ben,math) review(ben,chinese) review(nick,math) review(nick,chinese) ce(4) review(ben,english)
Optimization: -4
Answer: 1
review(harris,english) review(ben,math) review(ben,chinese) review(nick,math) review(nick,chinese) ce(4) review(ben,english)
Optimization: -4
Answer: 2
review(harris,english) review(ben,math) review(ben,chinese) review(nick,math) review(nick,chinese) ce(4) review(nick,english)
Optimization: -4
OPTIMUM FOUND
```

Not sure if this is what you want. You might as well refer to clingo guide regarding the parameter of `--opt-mode`:

> **--opt-mode=mode** Conﬁgure handling of optimization statements. Available values for **mode** are:
>
> **opt** Compute an optimal model (requires --models=0).
>
> **enum** Enumerate models with costs less than or equal to some ﬁxed bound
> (cf. --opt-bound).
>
> **optN** Compute optimum, then enumerate optimal models.
>
> **ignore** Ignore any optimization statements during computation.